# NSPredicate that calls test method to fetch results from Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am not quite sure how to word this question without explaining what I am trying to do.

I have a managed object context filled with (essentially) circles that have an x,y coord for the center point and a radius.

I would like to construct a predicate for my core data retrieval that will find all circles that overlap with a given circle.

I can write a boolean method that tests this and returns true or false, but my problem is that I don't know how to call this testing method in my predicate.

in pseudo-code, I am trying to do this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate (if [testOverlapWithCenterAt:centerOfGivenObjectInContext andRadius:radiusOfGivenObjectInContext]);
```

Perhaps NSPredicate isn't even the best way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am starting to think that using NSExpression to get the data I need to test may be the way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `predicateWithBlock` instance method of `NSPredicate`. Give it a try.